# How are dust and fees related?

Tags: transaction-fees, dust

When sending a transaction now, I get the prompt:
`The transaction fee is 0.010000000000, of which 0.006000000000 is dust from change. Is this okay?  (Y/Yes/N/No)`. What does that mean, is it that the fees would have been only 0.004 (or 0.006) but the client wants to round that up to 0.01?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a minor bug due to the dust threshold (0.01 XMR) being higher than the current fee (0.002 XMR per kB). This is fixed in [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1216) pull request.

> What does that mean, is it that the fees would have been only 0.004 (or 0.006) but the client wants to round that up to 0.01?

Basically yes.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to go around that and make the client pay just the fee in the current version?

Comment: Not if you are using precompiled binaries, i.e., those available on the getmonero website. However, if you are able to compile yourself you could include that aforementioned PR.

Comment: I see, thanks. But otherwise, how long should it take for that PR to become available in the binaries, do we have to wait for the ringCT hard fork, or can we expect it to be included before that?